# HTML files do not detect Typescript variables for Angular 6 in VS2017 15.7 [Intellisense]

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, intellisense, angular6

Just ported our application into a VS .NET Core 2.1 app, everything is working fine but when we are writing the .html files there is no code completion.

In the VS Code it works perfectly. I'll attach some images.

Here you can see that in the `.ts` file intellisense works fine:

**`header.component.ts`**

[image: First]

Then in the `.html` file, you can't access any variables from the `.ts` file.

**`header.component.html`**

[image: Seconds]

As you can see, nothing shows up.

**Using the latest Typescript in the properties of the project.**

Comment: you can't use this in html file